# function to create new column with defined parameters python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

i have this DF

[image]

How can I do this to get the 'mark' from the last day of the previous month in other column

Sample df that I filled in manually

[image]

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Found':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
       'Date':['14/10/2021','19/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','20/09/2021','20/10/2021','29/10/2021','15/10/2021','10/09/2021'],
      ## 'LastDayMonth':['29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','30/09/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021'],
       'Mark':[1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3,2]

      })
df

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['LastDayDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + BMonthEnd(0)
df['LastDayDatePrev'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) - pd.DateOffset(months=1)

mark_last_day = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x['Date']==x['LastDayMonth'], 1)]


   df = df.merge(df.loc[df['Date'] == df['LastDayDate'], ['Found','LastDayDate','Mark']],
     on=['Found', 'LastDayDate'],
     how='left', suffixes=['', '_LastDayDate'])
```

I added a practical example.

[image]

Comment: `BMonthEnd()` is not defined

Comment: Do you just want one month ago from each date or the end of the previous month? Your "LastDayDatePrev" shows "2021-09-14" but your words ("the last day of the previous month") seem to imply you want "2021-09-30". Which is it?

Comment: Also your dates in the "Date" column are not unique. So for the first row in your output, how do you decide which "Mark" should be returned for the Date "2021-10-29"? (There are both 2 and 3 for this date)

Comment: My intention is to use the last date of the previous month for me, it doesn't matter if it is the day 09-14 or the day 09-30 because I would use BMonthEnd

Comment: I wanted a new column where the value is 1.166978 is 1.49920 which is the value of the previous month and where it is 1.49920 is 1.248873 and so on